# How to specify BRDF measurement

Tags: optics, scattering, measurements

As a person who will be using the scattering measurement results (in Zemax), I was asked to prepare the specs for the [BRDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_reflectance_distribution_function) measurement. However I've never done it until now, so help would be greatly appreciated. I have a few questions:

1. What is a realistic range of illumination / detection angles for BRDF measurement?
2. What angular step is typical for elevation and azimuthal angles?
3. What dynamic range should we expect?
4. How do we take polarization into account? Is there a standard procedure? I could find it neither in the [Zemax explanation of BRDF](http://kb-en.radiantzemax.com/Knowledgebase/BSDF-Data-Interchange-File-Format-Specification), nor anywhere online.

The measurements will be executed at 10.6 um and possibly other IR wavelengths.

**UPDATE:** For common interest, I will put here some information I already have.

Zemax cannot measure at 10 um (350...1050 nm only) and usually perform measurement at 5 incident angles in the range of 0...75°. They do not perform polarization-sensitive measurement. Information is [available at their web-site](http://www.zemax.com/services/measurement-services/scatter-and-appearance).

Comment: What kinds of materials will you be measuring?  Anyway, BRDF is an angle, so unless you have a need for measuring a specific polarization, don't :-) . Just measure total power into the collection angle.   Perhaps you can find some tech papers or manuals at places like  http://surfaceoptics.com/products/reflectometers-emissometers/soc200/?gclid=CMew0O7ayb4CFbIDOgodbCcAjQ

Comment: +1 Nice question. To measure all materials from perfect mirror to absoulte black diffusor (2% of incident light is cosine distributed in hemisphere) your detector needs a large dynamic range. Can you select a range of materials between these two criteria? To rephrase it: Do you want to measure blackout materials to stray light reduction or optical media?

Comment: @StefanBischof: We need to measure the construction materials, which have been chosen for their mechanical, not optical properties. Moreover, to make things cheep, we do not specify the surface properties to the suppliers. That's why we do not know much about them a priori. An extruded tube can have a very smooth surface while a milled part can be quite rough.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: If I do not measure polarization, how can I distinguish between high and low reflectivity of s and p polarizations close to Brewster angle? The system is working with a laser, so polarization is relevant there. BTW, thanks for the link, I sent them the request.

Comment: If you want to measure s & p BRDF, then you'll need to have a polarized source, since in general the reflected light won't maintain polarization.